# Specify Model type in Administrate dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an administrate dashboard `school_dashboard.rb`:

```
require "administrate/base_dashboard"

class SchoolDashboard < Administrate::BaseDashboard

  ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    students: Field::HasMany.with_options(class_name: "User"),
    teachers: Field::HasMany.with_options(class_name: "User"),
    id: Field::Number,
    name: Field::String,
    created_at: Field::DateTime,
    updated_at: Field::DateTime,
  }

...
end
```

I have a `User` model that has the following scope:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:student, :teacher, :admin]

  # scopes
  scope :students, -> { where(role: User.roles[:student]) }
  scope :teachers, -> { where(role: User.roles[:teacher]) }
  scope :admins, -> { where(role: User.roles[:admin]) }

...
end
```

Is it possible to specify a scope in my administrate dashboard? I'd like to somehow specify students have the `:role => User.roles[:student]` either by using my scope or by passing in a where clause, but I don't see this in the [Administrate](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate) code anywhere.

Comment: Not sure it'll work because I assume you want the javascript and I'm not sure how that fits in but you could create new fields for them and inherit from the has_many field in administrate, setting the candidate_resources method explicitly to those scopes.  Another approach would be to create classes for each of them in models that you define a default scope on and pass that class to `with_options`.  Why is role an enum anyway?

Comment: 1) I think I'd rather have one `User` model with a role column. 2) `why is it a enum?` because I'm dumb and don't know a better way? 3) I don't think I want the javascript. I was thinking of overwriting the rails controller if I have to though.

Comment: Have you considered using single table inheritance instead of an enum?  I can't see you switching a user between student and teacher.  That way you'd have a student and teacher class inheriting from user and you can pass that to administrate.  Would that work?

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. I guess I'll have to learn about that. Although, I'm pretty sure Screech became principal later, so maybe students can become teachers...

Comment: Nice reference.  For STI you need a type column in the db.  Then if you do `Student.new.save` rails will save a record in the user table with the type of "Student"

Comment: Why not just use Single Table Inheritance? This way, student, teacher and admin all inherit from a `User` model, the parent model.